# What equivalent examplematcher in C# .net core

Tags: java, c#, entity-framework

In Java, I can use ExampleMatcher function to create query with search/filter functionality. Is any equivalent that function in c#.net core. Currently, I'm using Entityframework core.

Thank You

Some example in jave :

```
ExampleMatcher matcher = ExampleMatcher.matching().withStringMatcher(ExampleMatcher.StringMatcher.CONTAINING)
.withIgnoreNullValues().withIgnoreCase();

Example<Bahan> example = Example.of(bahanExample, matcher);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is any equivalent that function in c#.net core. Currently, I'm using Entityframework core.

No.  Queries in EF are built primarily using a set of language features called [Language-Integrated Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/) (LINQ), which enables you to write queries directly in C#.